# How do I backup a build process in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

How do I back up the build process (e.g. run this PowerShell script, run the build whenever a commit to VCS happens, *not* the build data) in TeamCity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an *Adimistrator*, log in, go the *Administration* page and look down the left side. Under *Server Administration*, toward the bottom of the list, is **Backup**. What is backed up varies by version. On mine (v8.1.1) the "Basic" setting says that the backup scope is (emphasis mine):

- database
- **server settings, projects and builds configurations**, plugins
- supplementary data (settings history, triggers states, plugins data, etc.)